# How to clip an image by a shape other than a rectangle?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, win-universal-app, clip

We are clipping an image by a rectangle as can be seen in the attached image:

[image]

The image inside, shaped like the sun, is clipped to a rectangle inside the purple house shaped polygon. However I would like clip the Sun to the entire house shaped polygon.

I was using XAML code like this:

```
<Image x:Name="Sun"
       Source="Assets/Sun.png"
       HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Image.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry>

        </RectangleGeometry>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

However XAML for UWP allows only RectangleGeometry.

Is there another way to achieve the clipping?

Thx

Comment: Show me your polygon and I could probably show you another way. Only limitation I have at the moment is they've not let us load win10 at work yet so I have to freehand without testing since I can't load a UWP proj up yet, or at least not until I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add whatever shape you want, then fill it with an `ImageBrush`. This clips the image to your shape. This example is for a circle:

```
<Ellipse>
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush
            Stretch="UniformToFill"
            ImageSource="Assets/Sun.png" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: Thx! Will try tomorrow.